# FreqDist Python ... at the end issue

Tags: python

When I try to print FreqDist object , I get "..." in the end of the print?
I tried looking for it on the internet but couldn't find.

please let me know where I am going wrong.

code :

```
for word in nltk.word_tokenize(lin):
    fdist.inc(word)

print fdist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fdist`, it returns a list of key-value pairs. You have to print them out using a loop. Something like below should work:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

lin = "A frequency distribution for the outcomes of an experiment. A frequency distribution records the number of times each outcome of an experiment has occurred. For example, a frequency distribution could be used to record the frequency of each word type in a document. Formally, a frequency distribution can be defined as a function mapping from each sample to the number of times that sample occurred as an outcome."

fdist = nltk.FreqDist()

for word in word_tokenize(lin):
    fdist.inc(word)

for f in fdist:
    print f, fdist[f]
```

The result is:

```
frequency 5
of 5
a 4
distribution 4
the 4
an 3
each 3
, 2
A 2
as 2
be 2
number 2
outcome 2
sample 2
times 2
to 2
. 1
For 1
Formally 1
can 1
could 1
defined 1
document. 1
example 1
experiment 1
experiment. 1
for 1
from 1
function 1
has 1
in 1
mapping 1
occurred 1
occurred. 1
outcomes 1
record 1
records 1
that 1
type 1
used 1
word 1
[Finished in 1.5s]
```

Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

Another approach:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

lin = "A frequency distribution for the outcomes of an experiment. A frequency distribution records the number of times each outcome of an experiment has occurred. For example, a frequency distribution could be used to record the frequency of each word type in a document. Formally, a frequency distribution can be defined as a function mapping from each sample to the number of times that sample occurred as an outcome."

tokens = word_tokenize(lin)
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)

for f in fdist:
    print f, fdist[f]
```

Output is the same.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you by clicking on the checkmark near the top of this post. This is how we say thanks in SO.